# How make search function in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I have `UITableView` inside `UIViewController`…
Now I want add a search bar to make search to all of data in `UITableView`…
I really confused with that.
Please help…

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below link. This will help you 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view